# Close as off-topic and/or flag for migration?

Tags: discussion, scope

Should we be closing, flagging, or both closing and flagging questions that are off-topic per the faq?

For example, here's one on Backtrack :
https://askubuntu.com/questions/220243/backtrack-gui-crashes-after-mousklick .

It's currently in the review queue for closing.

Answer (score 4):

Closing, yes absolutely. As for migration, if it's a *good* question it can be considered for migration. Otherwise we don't want bad questions (crap) migrated to us so we will not migrate "crap" questions to other sites.

Comment: Thanks.  And this one probably falls into the 'bad' group.

Comment: Yeah, definitely.